# MODX - Как создать MIGX внутри другого MIGX?

Tags: modx, migx

Добрый день!
Никак не получается вывести MIGX внутри другого MIGX, даже скорее не получается вывести во frontend значение внутреннего MIGX. Ниже представлен код который я использую.

mainTV (slider):

```
[
{"caption":"Info", "fields": [
    {"field":"slider_title","caption":"Header row","inputTV":"slider_title_row"},
    {"field":"image","caption":"Image","inputTV":"image_helper"}
]}
]
```

subTV (slider_title_row):

```
[
   {"caption":"Header row", "fields": [
    {"field":"title_row","caption":"Header row","inputTVtype":"text"}
   ]}
]
```

main call:

```
<div class="main-carousel">
    [[!getImageList? &tvname=`slider` &tpl=`Slider_title.tpl`]]
</div>
```

chank Slider_title.tpl:

```
<div class="main-carousel__item carousel-item" style="background-image:url([[+image]]);">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-item__description">
      <h2>[[!getImageList?
            &tpl=`Slider_title_row.tpl`
            &value=`[[+slider_title]]`
           ]]
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

chank Slider_title_row.tpl:

```
<div>[[+title_row]]</div>
```

[[+title_row]] не выводится.

Comment: Столкнулся с той же проблемой... Вы решили как надо выводить?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вывести поля migx внутри migx, создай еще одно TV с типом migx и в разметке формы, в inputTV напиши название нового TV. 
Должно получится как-то так:

```
{
"field": "field_name",
"caption": "Заголовок",
"inputTV": "new_migx_tv"
}
```

А выводить через параметр `value=[[+new_migx_tv]]` в getImageList либо через fenom